# Nextjs customizing dark and light mode using tailwind

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

Does anyone know how to customize dark and light modes in NextJs using tailwind? I'm using the react-themes library but it's pretty vague about setting up the rest of your classes so that they also change color based on theme.

Here's what I have:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
:root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--foreground);
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  background-color: var(--background);
}

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: "#0B0B45";
    --foreground: "white";
  }
}
```

This works in terms of switching to black when I click the dark mode button but it doesn't use the color I provided and instead using a dark gray default color

Anyone know any work around?

Comment: You can try [tw-colors](https://github.com/L-Blondy/tw-colors). It makes it super easy to theme your apps